# Automatic column value update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe I'm totally wrong and it's not pssible to do in MySQL. But, what I wanted to do is to fill out column row base in a select query:

For example:

Table 1:

```
IdNode  NodeName  NodeContact NodeStatus Nodegroup
  1     Machine1     IT           1         IT
  2     Machine2     IT           0         IT
  3     Machine3     IT           1         IT
  4     Machine4     IT           1        Others
  4     Machine5     IT           1        Others
```

Table 2

```
IdGroup  GroupName   NodesManagedbyGroup
   1         IT             ??
   2         others         ??
```

Having those two tables, I would like to fill out (automatically) all rows in column `NodesManagedbyGroup` in the table2.

Manually it would be:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 where MemberOfGroup='IT';`

result value Int = 3

Then

`update table2 NodesManagedbyGroup = 3 where GroupName='IT';`

There is any way that MySQL do it for me automatically

Comment: You don't want to store calculated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to do this - you'd create triggers for insert, update and delete on table 1 to update table 2.

This is generally a bad idea though - it's duplicating information around the database, denormalizing the schema.

Alternatively, you can create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which calculates this data on the fly and behaves like a table when querying.

Comment: I doubt 'automatically' means something related to triggers. For me, OP just want to avoid manual selection of values for updating per each group

Comment: Triggers works for me. But finally I decide to change my way and dont duplicate info in the database, as @Neville point out. I'lll try to do some inner join queries and get the result from different tables. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [multiple `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) syntax with selecting counts in subquery as a sample:

```
UPDATE 
  table2 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS gcount, Nodegroup FROM table1 GROUP BY Nodegroup) AS counts 
    ON table2.GroupName=counts.Nodegroup 
SET 
  table2.NodesManagedbyGroup=table1.gcount
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a job that performs a stored procedure every 15 minutes or so?